# Gdb not printing pointers correctly from a STL map

Tags: c++, pointers, stl, gdb

I am debugging a core using gdb. I am trying to print a few maps in the frame. The maps contain pointers to structures as their value. However some of the maps are printed incorrectly while some are printed correctly.

```
Eg:
map1 < int, void* >
map2 < int, A* >

gdb> pmap map1 
10 0x7f2bbec0f4e0

gdb> pmap map2
20 0x7f2bbec00000
```

Why are the pointers from map2 being printed incorrectly?

Answer (score 2):

There is no GDB `pmap` command. Possibly you are using long-obsolete stlviews, like [this](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/src/dbinit_stl_views-1.03.txt) one.

Modern GDB distributions come with python pretty-printers, which can print maps just fine. Try `p map1` and `p map2` instead.

> Why are the pointers from map2 being printed incorrectly?

You haven't shown any evidence that `map2` is printed incorrectly. For all we know it contains a single `20, 0x7f2bbec00000` element.

P.S. This looks bogus:

```
map1 < int, void* > 
map2 < int, A* >
```

What you probably mean is:

```
std::map<int, void*> map1;
std::map<int, A*> map2;
```

In the future, you will get more useful answers if you show *actual* code, not an incorrect rendition of it.